# How to combine a text and a number when the readin is from excel in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an excel Data containining 5×6 table. And in the last two columns i have value1  and value2 . In both this the values are number and text such as in first value it has '3' and 'age' and in  value 2 it has '5','gender' to which i need to genearate a 4x2 combinations cell . Also as i am using 2019b matlab version i cannot use the combinations built in function from matlab. Please let me know how acan i create a combinations?

I tried combvec but its only for double and not char data type

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the excel structure so it would be clearer? also an example of the desired output would be useful

Comment: using 'num2str' or 'str2num' functions may solve your problem, but to be more clear, please provide an example as @FerroLuca mentioned above.